# Why does filtering a QuerySet behave differently for user vs. superuser?

Tags: python, django

When logged in as my superuser, 'admin', I'm able to filter a QuerySet by any field. However when I am logged in as a regular user I'm only able to filter by the field 'user'. Trying to filter by any other field returns an empty list.

```
class Question(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    verb = models.ForeignKey(Verb)
    voice = models.ForeignKey(Voice)
    ...
```

This works fine:

```
def next_question(request):
    user = request.user
    q = Question.objects.filter(user=user)
```

This works fine when logged in as a superuser but fails as a regular user (`myverb` is an instance of my `Verb` model):

```
def next_question(request):
    user = request.user
    q = Question.objects.filter(user=user, verb=myverb)
```

I'm new to Django (though not to Python) so am I missing some kind of permission that I need to set for regular users which would fix this behaviour?

**Edited to add images showing the items in the database**

Example question for superuser, 'admin':

[image: Example object for admin]

Example question for user 'jamie':

[image: Example object for jamie]

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between superuser and regular user in this ORM query.

You simply don't have any `Question` instances with both `myverb` verb field and `request.user` user field.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The super user is also a normal user.

Depending on what the value of the user variable is set to at the time (I assume it's the currently logged in user) You could interpret your query as this: all questions where the related user is the currently logged in user.

Therefore if you see no results when you are logged in as someone else it is because you really don't have any questions you are associated with.

If you are sure that you should have results it may be that your user variable is not set to what you think it is. Make sure it's value is correct.

Ie user = request.user

Comment: I've checked the user variable and for 'jamie' it's `<SimpleLazyObject: <User: jamie>>` while for 'admin' it's `<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>`. Also see the edit to the question which shows the objects do exist in the database.

Comment: It should work then. Must be something else. How are you deciding if it works or not.

Comment: I've got it. I'm copying all the Questions from the 'admin' account when creating a new user, changing the `user` field but not changing the `verb` field, or the other fields. That means I'm comparing two different Verb objects so getting no results back.

Comment: Excellent! If you don't use it already try pudb it's awesome. And checkout django debug toolbar

Comment: I'm running/debugging in PyDev mostly, but at the moment I've been adding assert statements and inspecting the debug log in Chrome. Will check out pudb and the toolbar.